# Failed to register layer: Error processing tar file (exit status 1): invalid argument

Tags: docker, arm

I am trying to run Docker hello-world on `armel` platform. However, I am getting `tar: invalid argument` error as shown. I am Running Docker in `chroot` environment. Hoping to get some pointers...

```
#./docker run hello-world
DEBU[2019-05-27T13:59:01.403488020Z] Calling GET /_ping

DEBU[2019-05-27T13:59:01.406786120Z] Calling POST /v1.39/containers/create

DEBU[2019-05-27T13:59:01.407900660Z] form data: 
{"AttachStderr":true,"AttachStdin":false,"AttachStdout":true,"Cmd":null,"Domainname":"","Entrypoint":null,"Env":[],"HostConfig":{"AutoRemove":false,"Binds":null,"BlkioDeviceReadBps":null,"BlkioDeviceReadIOps":null,"BlkioDeviceWriteBps":null,"BlkioDeviceWriteIOps":null,"BlkioWeight":0,"BlkioWeightDevice":[],"CapAdd":null,"CapDrop":null,"Cgroup":"","CgroupParent":"","ConsoleSize":[0,0],"ContainerIDFile":"","CpuCount":0,"CpuPercent":0,"CpuPeriod":0,"CpuQuota":0,"CpuRealtimePeriod":0,"CpuRealtimeRuntime":0,"CpuShares":0,"CpusetCpus":"","CpusetMems":"","DeviceCgroupRules":null,"Devices":[],"DiskQuota":0,"Dns":[],"DnsOptions":[],"DnsSearch":[],"ExtraHosts":null,"GroupAdd":null,"IOMaximumBandwidth":0,"IOMaximumIOps":0,"IpcMode":"","Isolation":"","KernelMemory":0,"Links":null,"LogConfig":{"Config":{},"Type":""},"MaskedPaths":null,"Memory":0,"MemoryReservation":0,"MemorySwap":0,"MemorySwappiness":-1,"NanoCpus":0,"NetworkMode":"default","OomKillDisable":false,"OomScoreAdj":0,"PidMode":"","PidsLimit":0,"PortBindings":{},"Privileged":false,"PublishAllPorts":false,"ReadonlyPaths":null,"ReadonlyRootfs":false,"RestartPolicy":{"MaximumRetryCount":0,"Name":"no"},"SecurityOpt":null,"ShmSize":0,"UTSMode":"","Ulimits":null,"UsernsMode":"","VolumeDriver":"","VolumesFrom":null},"Hostname":"","Image":"hello-world","Labels":{},"NetworkingConfig":{"EndpointsConfig":{}},"OnBuild":null,"OpenStdin":false,"StdinOnce":false,"Tty":false,"User":"","Volumes":{},"WorkingDir":""}

Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally

DEBU[2019-05-27T13:59:01.413317800Z] Calling GET /v1.39/info

WARN[2019-05-27T13:59:01.414791760Z] Could not get operating system name: Error opening /usr/lib/os-release: open /usr/lib/os-release: no such file or directory

DEBU[2019-05-27T13:59:01.438037600Z] Calling POST /v1.39/images/create?fromImage=hello-world&tag=latest

DEBU[2019-05-27T13:59:01.438664080Z] Trying to pull hello-world from https://registry-1.docker.io v2

DEBU[2019-05-27T13:59:02.340561960Z] Pulling ref from V2 registry: hello-world:latest

DEBU[2019-05-27T13:59:02.340799640Z] docker.io/library/hello-world:latest resolved to a manifestList object with 9 entries; looking for a unknown/arm match

DEBU[2019-05-27T13:59:02.340851620Z] found deprecated partial match for linux/arm/v8 with media type application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json, digest sha256:1e44d8bca6fb0464794555e5ccd3a32e2a4f6e44a20605e4e82605189904f44d
DEBU[2019-05-27T13:59:02.340898100Z] found deprecated partial match for linux/arm/v8 with media type application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json, digest sha256:d1fd2e204af0a2bca3ab033b417b29c76d7950ed29a44e427d1c4d07d14f04f9

DEBU[2019-05-27T13:59:02.340938600Z] found multiple matches in manifest list, choosing best match sha256:1e44d8bca6fb0464794555e5ccd3a32e2a4f6e44a20605e4e82605189904f44d
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world

DEBU[2019-05-27T13:59:02.498004860Z] pulling blob "sha256:590e13f69e4afcc08e9060a320ec5e4622d2771ace9dc26b024dc786fcb5b36e"
590e13f69e4a: Downloading 1.027kB/1.027kB
590e13f69e4a: Extracting 1.027kB/1.027kB
590e13f69e4a: Extracting 1.027kB/1.027kB

DEBU[2019-05-27T13:59:03.433254360Z] Cleaning up layer 22e8d4d817b6220a7884a028ba7b1e52b09f83b760a34acc3b9ffaf07f1f4cc4: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): invalid argument

INFO[2019-05-27T13:59:03.434607560Z] Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): invalid argument

./docker: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): invalid argument.

See './docker run --help'.

#./docker info
DEBU[2019-05-27T14:15:14.212268660Z] Calling GET /_ping

DEBU[2019-05-27T14:15:14.213233780Z] Calling GET /v1.39/info

WARN[2019-05-27T14:15:14.214784160Z] Could not get operating system name: Error opening /usr/lib/os-release: open /usr/lib/os-release: no such file or directory

Containers: 0

Running: 0

Paused: 0

Stopped: 0

Images: 0

Server Version: 18.09.4

Storage Driver: overlay2

Backing Filesystem: extfs

Supports d_type: true

Native Overlay Diff: true

Logging Driver: json-file

Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs

Plugins:

Volume: local

Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay

Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog

Swarm: inactive

Runtimes: runc

Default Runtime: runc

Init Binary: docker-init

containerd version: bb71b10fd8f58240ca47fbb579b9d1028eea7c84

runc version: 2b18fe1d885ee5083ef9f0838fee39b62d653e30

init version: fec3683

Kernel Version: 4.1.51-ws-symbol

OSType: linux

Architecture: aarch64

CPUs: 2

Total Memory: 870.7MiB

Name: (none)

ID: AWJE:2XHF:F6IX:AFBY:RKSO:ZAD5:QORR:OWBG:RXWM:UHBC:24JT:PT55

Docker Root Dir: /mnt/usb/docker

Debug Mode (client): false

Debug Mode (server): false

Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/

Labels:

Experimental: false

Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8

Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support

WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
```